# Can we estimate a missing Y value from a three factor experiment?

Tags: self-study, experiment-design, missing-data

In preparation for an examination I'm looking at some old questions, and I could use a little help with figuring out what to do here:

> In a three-factor experiment the researchers lost the results from experimental run 3. Oh no! However, higher order interactions can often be assumed to be negligible (i.e. equal to 0). Do we need to rerun the experiment or can we find x given this assumption? if yes, find x.
>
> ```
>       A    B    C    ABC    Y
> 1    -1   -1   -1    ?      7
> 2     1   -1   -1    ?      6
> 3    -1    1   -1    ?      x
> 4     1    1   -1    ?      5
> 5    -1   -1    1    ?      5
> 6     1   -1    1    ?      9
> 7    -1    1    1    ?      8
> 8     1    1    1    ?      7
> ```

I don't really know how to solve this, but my guess would be that we could do something like this:

1. Calculate the mean Y
2. Look at how A, B & C affects Y
3. Create a function that takes A,B,C and outputs Y
4. Input the A,B and C values, function outputs an estimated Y value

I can also be completely wrong and you have to do it in another way, any help is appreciated.

```
A first attempt at solving this according to my guess on how to solve this:
Calculate the mean Y = (7+6+5+5+9+8+7)/7 = 6.7

Calculate the effect A has on Y: 
Step1: mean Y when A ==  1: (6+5+9+7)/4 = 6.75
Step2: mean Y when A == -1: (7+5+8)/3 = 6.67
The Effect A has on Y: 6.75-6.67 = 0.08 
Since we have the two alternatives, divide with 2, 0.08/2 = 0.04


If we only had factor A in our experiment, we would use this function to  
calculate Y: 
6.7 + 0.04*x = Y, where x is either 1 or -1.


If we perform the same steps for B and C we get:
Y= mean of Y + (influence of A on Y)*x + (influence of B on Y)*x +     
(influence of C on Y)*x

Y = 6.7 + 0.04*x + -0.04*x + 0.625*x


To get ABC:
A          B           C        ABC
(-1   *    -1)    *    -1    =   -1
( 1   *    -1)    *    -1    =    1
(-1   *     1)    *    -1    =    1

ABC Effect = -0.625

Y = 6.7 + 0.04*x + -0.04*x + 0.625*x + -0.625x

Experimental run 3: Y = 6.7 + -0.04 + -0.04 + -0.625 + -0.625 = 5.37
```

Is this how you would do it?

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: Missing that one value creates an asymmetry in the experiment, making it clear that $A$ and $C$ ought to be involved differently than $B$ in your calculations. Note, too, that if you're going to tackle this one statistically, then "finding $x$" means giving a *prediction interval* for it, not just an estimate.

Comment: What method/formula should I be looking at to calculate a prediction interval instead of an estimate?

Answer (score 0):

First calculate the sign for ABC.

```
            A    B    C    ABC     Y
      1    -1   -1   -1    -1      7
      2     1   -1   -1     1      6
      3    -1    1   -1     1      x
      4     1    1   -1    -1      5
      5    -1   -1    1     1      5
      6     1   -1    1    -1      9
      7    -1    1    1    -1      8
      8     1    1    1     1      7
```

---

Then group Y with the positive and negative sign. So:

```
Negative    Positive
   7           6
   5           x
   9           5
   8           7
```

---

Next part is finding out x, we assume that x is 0:

$$\sum(positive)/n - \sum(negative)/n = 0 $$

$$\dfrac{(6+x+5+7)}8 - \dfrac{(7+5+9+8)}8 = 0$$
$$x = 11$$